# React Redux privilege related issue

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react application with different route page i.e Group Management, Role Management, User Management etc. Data is been fetched from API's.

A User can do some action or access a route page only when the user has the privilege for that particular action. Privileges are also fetched through API at the application loading time.

So the problem here is if privilege related to a logged in User is modified from Backend or in API. Now the logged in User will not be able to take particular action based on the earlier privilege as the privilege has been changed and the updated privilege are not been fetched.

Comment: The scenario is clear. What's the question exactly?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you asking how to handle managing permissions for a user who already has their permissions set in their reducer?

Comment: Are you asking how to sync privileges with the server?

Comment: The problem is how to know that privilege has been changed for the logged in User from server end.

Comment: So let's say User A is logged in and he has the permission for Group Management i.e User A can do CRUD operations. Now privilege get's updated from server end to Role Management. So if User A is accessing Group Management page now he won't be able to do CRUD operations for Group Management and User A is unaware of privilege that has been modified from server end. Hope that clarify the problem.

Comment: One option is, each time User A tries to do a CRUD operation, we call the API for checking his access(privilege), if he has the same access as before, we don't need to do anything, if his access has changed, we can force him to logout and again login with new access.
And the best way for implementing this scenario is using HOC https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: I thought of the same thing but it will slow down the application.

Comment: If you are thinking of a better performance, you can use ```GraphQL subscription``` and ```Apollo```, which it listen to the socket and update the UI whenever the data changing in t he back-end.
https://dev-blog.apollodata.com/tutorial-graphql-subscriptions-server-side-e51c32dc2951